# Trying to mount a Mac HFS+ encrypted disk

Tags: raspberry-pi, disk, macintosh, disk-encryption

**tl;dr** I'm having trouble mounting a disk in Buster using hfsplus formatted under Mac OS Extended (*Journaled*, *Encrypted*) that was created under Catalina.

This was asked on the [Pi exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/115844/unable-to-mount-disk-formatted-by-mac-catalina-on-buster) but they 'suggested' it was moved to here as was off-topic.

The scenario is that I have data on a portable drive that needs to be encrypted and read by a Pi that was created by a Mac and encrypted at the Mac OS level. Long term this data may need to be written to by the Pi itself maintaining encryption but that's not an issue to start with.

Buster is reasonably up to date (about a week or so behind) and I've installed HFS support:

```
sudo apt install hfsplus hfsutils hfsprogs gdisk
```

*sudo fdisk -l* reports:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: 024 HN-M101MBB  
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 4CA4A134-233E-4C5A-B402-9E61EA94F183

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1          40     409639     409600   200M EFI System
/dev/sda2      409640 1953262983 1952853344 931.2G Apple Core storage
/dev/sda3  1953262984 1953525127     262144   128M Apple boot
```

and *sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda* reports:

```
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.3

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: present

Found valid GPT with protective MBR; using GPT.
Disk /dev/sda: 1953525168 sectors, 931.5 GiB
Model: 024 HN-M101MBB  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 4CA4A134-233E-4C5A-B402-9E61EA94F183
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953525134
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 13 sectors (6.5 KiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640      1953262983   931.2 GiB   AF05  
   3      1953262984      1953525127   128.0 MiB   AB00  Booter
```

From the lack of a name on the gdisk output for the second partition I think it was formatted as 'Untitled'.

Trying a simple mount command `sudo mount -t hfsplus /dev/sda2 /mnt/Test-1TB/` I just get:

> mount: /mnt/Test-1TB: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda2, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Notes:

1. Disk is case insensitive
2. Read Only access is fine at this time - No writes are planned yet
3. Encryption is required under Policy / GDPR / Good Practice
4. Journaling cannot be dropped on HFS+ drives with encryption
5. I'm unable to mount this on a Mac and share from that box (no Macs at the location)
6. `fsck.hfsplus` reports QUICKCHECK ONLY; NO HFS SIGNATURE FOUND
7. The drive was correctly unmounted from the Mac
8. I can access the data fine from a Mac and copy to a ext4 drive short time - no a valid on-going fix though.
9. Using `sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw` does not help (as per Ubuntu fix [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/332315/how-to-read-and-write-hfs-journaled-external-hdd-in-ubuntu-without-access-to-os))
10. Paragon extFS for Mac does not support encrypted ext4 drives from what I can tell
11. Loathe to make the users life more complex by encrypting the data first and writing a file to disk as 'data' may include documents / pdfs etc.

Comment: The problem must be the encryption. You cannot mount an encrypted volume like that.